# How can I solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

How can I find a solution of the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\exp(x^2+ x)$$

Thanks!

Comment: Alpha obtains an [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%28x%29%27%27-exp%28x%5E2%2bx%29=0) in term of (imaginary) error function (this means that the primitive of the primitive of $e^{x^2+x}$ is not much more complicated than the primitive itself and that no elementary solution exists).

Comment: You can also integrate the Taylor series termwise.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be a primitive of $x \mapsto e^{x^2+x}$ and let $G$ be a primitive of $F$. Then $$y(x)=G(x)+C_1 x + C_2.$$

**Remark.** My answer is no joke: no elementary expression can be given to $F$ and $G$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x)$$
Integrating both sides with respect to **x**, we have 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\int f(x)~dx+A=\phi(x)+A$$
Integrating again 
$$y=\int \phi(x)~dx+Ax+B=\chi(x)+Ax+B$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^{x^2+x}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\int e^{x^2+x}~dx$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\int_k^xe^{x^2+x}~dx+C_1$

$y=\int\int_k^xe^{x^2+x}~dx~dx+\int C_1~dx$

$y=\int_k^x\int_k^xe^{x^2+x}~dx~dx+C_1x+C_2$

By http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html,

$y=\int_k^x(x-t)e^{t^2+t}~dt+C_1x+C_2$